# What does the phrase "'splodier Flatulence" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

Please help me figure out the meaning of the phrase "'splodier Flatulence" in the following text from the description of the game Giant Dancing Plushie:

> We enjoy pulling off awesome combos that unleash car-crushing disco
> blasts and tank-smashing eye lasers. A green Oinkster the pig with
> **’splodier Flatulence**?

Here is a brief description of the game from 148 Apps:

> Giant Dancing Plushies is a game where you control building-sized
> stuffed animals as they strut down the street, destroying cars, tanks,
> and more. You can move these giant animals one step at a time, but the
> game challenges you to do it to the beat of either the in-game
> soundtrack or whatever music you might be listening to at the time.

Comment: These game descriptions may not be written by a native speaker. 'Splodier flatulence' sounds like baby-talk for 'explosive flatulence'. Is this game intended for children and very young teenagers?

Comment: I would take a guess that 'splodier' is a play on the word 'exploding', flatulence being what it is, and games being games.

Comment: I expect the pig farts result in exciting screen effects. In informal discussion related to TV, movies, games, etc, 'splody ('explody') seems to mean 'vividly explosive'. From a blog about special effects: 'All those big bright movie explosions ... gawd, aren’t they boring ... The 'splosions may be getting 'splodier, smearing the screen with an improbable whirr of brightly coloured nonsense, but the end result of all this frenetically frantic action is a snoozefest.' This game sounds profoundly infantile.

Comment: Where is the text you are asking about from exactly? The game description doesn't help us as much as seeing that sentence in context would.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I don't know about the target players.

Comment: @ColleenV Unfortunately, the text is not available online.